# How can I get the format the results of a CheckboxsetField as a comma separated string in SilverStripe?

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to create some filters for a datalist. I'd like the user to be able to select one or multiple filters from a list of tags and then spit out a list of objects based on those filters. All is good using this code to grab data based on the URL params being sent...

```
public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
{
    // ...
    if($tagsParam = $request->getVar('tags')) {
        $articles = new ArrayList();
        $tagids = explode(",", $tagsParam);
        foreach($tagids AS $tagid) {
            $tag = Category::get()->byID($tagid);
            $articleitems = $tag->getManyManyComponents('Articles')->sort('Date DESC');
            foreach($articleitems AS $articleitem) {
                $articles->push($articleitem);
            }
        }
    }
    $data = array (
        'Articles' => $articles
    );
    if($request->isAjax()) {
        return $this->customise($data)->renderWith('ListItems');
    }
    return $data;
}
```

That code works fine with a URL like mysite.com/?tags=1,2,3

My issue comes with trying to generate that URL based on the filters built with a CheckboxSetField. Here is my code for that...

```
public function ArticlesSearchForm()
{
    $tagsmap = $this->getTags()->map('ID', 'Title')->toArray();
    $form = Form::create(
        $this,
        'ArticlesSearchForm',
        FieldList::create(
            CheckboxSetField::create('tags')
                ->setSource($tagsmap)
        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('doArticlesSearch','Search')
        )
    );

    $form->setFormMethod('GET')
        ->setFormAction($this->Link())
        ->disableSecurityToken()
        ->loadDataFrom($this->request->getVars());

    return $form;
}
```

When the user submits that form, the URL generated is something along the lines of mysite.com?tags%5B1%5D=1&tags%5B2%5D=2&action_doArticlesSearch=Search  Obviously, it's passing the values as an array. How can I pass a simple comma separated list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to change the return of `CheckboxSetField`, I'd recommend changing your code. Given you are converting the comma-separated list list into an array already here:

`$tagids = explode(",", $tagsParam);`

Something like this, will skip this step:

```
public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
{
    // ...
    if($tagsParam = $request->getVar('tags')) {
        $articles = new ArrayList();
        //This has a minor risk of going bad if $tagsParam is neither an
        //array of a comma-separated list
        $tagids = is_array($tags) ? $tagsParam : explode(",", $tagsParam);
```

Comment: Ah, that works! I'd still prefer the cleaner URL, but I'll take working over not working any day ;) Thanks! For anyone who may be looking at this down the road, you'd just need to update the $tagsid variable to `$tagids = is_array($tagsParam) ? $tagsParam : explode(",", $tagsParam);`